# HTML elements to new line control?

Tags: html, css

I have a following situation, [here is short version in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwp0gem9/1/)

So I have `.main` div, with two div-s inside, next to each other.

`.first-div` contains dynamic number of links (`a` elements each with different content and width).

`.second-div` contains icon with fixed width.

What I am trying to achieve is, in case there too many links in `first-div` (more than it can fit in full width of `.main` div), by default only show what can fit in single line/row, and by clicking on `icon` expand and  show all links in multiple rows.

I tried on click to add/remove class to `first-div` that will have:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

but this doesnt work, since it cuts some links, depending on width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

If this is what you want, please read this, what I've changed:

- Add *display: block* to links (so that they will split into lines)
- Add *height: 22px* and *overflow-y : hidden* to .main (to hide other
  links)
- Add script to toggle the overflow-y between *hidden* and *initial*
  (to show or hide other links on click on btn)

```js
var status = 0;
$(".second-div").click(function(){
if (status == 0) {
$(".main").css("overflow-y", "initial");
status = 1;
} else {
$(".main").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
status = 0;
}
})
```

```css
.main {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 22px;
}

.first-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
}

.first-div a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}

.second-div a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="first-div">
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-div">
    <a>Icon</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, with this solution each link will be in its own row/line. What I need is to have all links that can fit in one row/line, but only first row/line will be visible until someone clicks on `icon`. I hope I was clear.

Comment: @user3921420 hi, i've edited my answer, please check if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: inline-flex`

```css
.main {
  min-height: 75px;
}

.first-div {
 width: calc(100% - 70px);
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.first-div a {
  padding: 5px;
}

.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first-div">
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-div">
    <i>Icon</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gwp0gem9/3/

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="first-div" id="thediv">
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
    <a>Element</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-div" onClick="change()">
    <i>Icon</i>
  </div>
</div>

.main {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.first-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second-div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
}

var toggle= true;

function change() {

if (toggle){
  document.getElementById("thediv").style.whiteSpace = "normal";
  document.getElementById("thediv").style.overflow = "auto";
    toggle = !toggle;
}
else
{
  document.getElementById("thediv").style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
  document.getElementById("thediv").style.overflow = "hidden";
    toggle = !toggle;


}


}
```

Is this what you needed? Clicking on the icon now toggles the behaviour. Let us know if this is what you needed via comments or accepting the answer please.